# why jquery's hasClass on an element is not working

Tags: jquery

On click of the tab (Quantity Tab )   i am generating unique ID for the lablel  id as

For Tab1 it is

```
703_KK_0_KK_0tab1
 703_KK_1_KK_0tab1
```

For Tab2 it is

```
703_KK_0_KK_0tab2
703_KK_0_KK_0tab2
```

On selection/unselection of the  checkobox  the framework add a class **ui-checkbox-on** and **ui-checkbox-off** respectively .

The issue i am facing is that it is unable to remember the state of the selction

**Scenario to produce :**

Click on **Tab 1** , select some check boxes and navigate to **Tab 2** and then back to **Tab1** , it is failing to remember the  selected toppings ??\

Please see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/82/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You're creating new elements everytime the tabs are clicked, how are the new elements supposed to know what you did to the old elements, which you've since removed ?

Comment: But when selection or unselection i am adding the class to id know and while displaying it runs through that for loop know so whats the issue ??

Comment: @adeneo , may be i am unclear of what i am doing could you please let e know how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: It can't be that hard to grok? The functions you're calling on switching tabs creates a lot of HTML that is inserted. This happens every time, and you create new elements that don't remember the state of the old elements, regardless of what you class you add ?

Comment: Better to hide/show tab content rather than delete and recreate every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way of handling this issue is to use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Below  checkbox is searched for sessionStorage item based on its id.

```
for (var k = 0; k < toppings.length; k++) {

    var topping_name = toppings[k].topping_name;
    var dyn_qt_val = vendoritemsid + '_KK_' + k + '_KK_' + i + 'tab' + tabnumber;

    var isChecked = false;

    var value = sessionStorage.getItem(dyn_qt_val + "_checkbox");

    //obtain checkbox checked value from session if it exist
    if ((value === "false") || (value === "true")) {
        isChecked = sessionStorage.getItem(dyn_qt_val + "_checkbox") === "true" ? true: false;
    }

    var dyn_key = $("#" + dyn_qt_val).hasClass("ui-checkbox-on");
    if (dyn_key) {
        m_class = "ui-checkbox-on";
    } else {
        m_class = "";
    }
    if (isChecked) { //checked
        toppdata += '<li><form><input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox-mini-0"  id="' + dyn_qt_val + '_checkbox" data-mini="true" checked/><label class="' + m_class + '"  id="' + dyn_qt_val + '_label"    for="' + dyn_qt_val + '_checkbox">' + topping_name + ' </label></form></li>';
    } else { //not checked
        toppdata += '<li><form><input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox-mini-0"  id="' + dyn_qt_val + '_checkbox" data-mini="true"/><label class="' + m_class + '"  id="' + dyn_qt_val + '_label"    for="' + dyn_qt_val + '_checkbox">' + topping_name + ' </label></form></li>';
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/tdzfhzjy/86/)

Those checked values are saved in the onclick handlers for checkboxes.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event) {

    $(this).removeClass('ui-checkbox-off');
    $(this).addClass('ui-checkbox-on');

    //save to session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem($(this).next().attr("id"), true);  
});


$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event) {

    $(this).removeClass('ui-checkbox-on');
    $(this).addClass('ui-checkbox-off');

    //save to session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem($(this).next().attr("id"), false);

});
```

I hope this helps :-) Btw, I noticed that you're using quite a lot of form tags + I changed some of the dynamics ids above (checkbox and label).